# cdi @produces method gives infinite loop while get Iterator

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, openwebbeans

good day. i trying to use producer method to obtain proper bean for injection.
it works fine when i call

```
Instance<HttpAmClientTransport> clienttrnsportI = instance.select(HttpAmClientTransport.class);
HttpAmClientTransport clienttrnsport = clienttrnsportI.get();
```

where HttpAmClientTransport.class is local interface of injected bean
but if i want to call iterator on instance

```
Iterator<AmClientTransport> aaa = instance.iterator();
```

than this cause recursive factory class creation (with execution @Produces method)
there is discussion here with answer by Brian Blonski 
[Java CDI: Dynamically selecting an implementation based on qualifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992641/java-cdi-dynamically-selecting-an-implementation-based-on-qualifier)

but in my case recursion appears when i get iterator , not obtain bean instance by .next()

also i need your advice. in fact i have several Transport Beans with their own local interfaces and several Clients beans in which i must inject particular transport. the type of client (rest soap or db) and transport qualifier (secure or not) will be given in config file and it may change. i thought that i could hardcoded some client configuration constraints in annotation with enumeration variable with necessary mapping , that would contains Transport interface class.
those interfaces (one for each client bean ) would be implemented by Transport beans (and it may be that some client implements all interfaces as it suits for every client) but the is some question.
how can i filter out all transport beans that implements that client-specific interface in producer method
if i change

```
Instance<HttpAmClientTransport> clienttrnsport = instance.select(HttpAmClientTransport.class);
```

to

```
Instance<RestfulAmClientTransport> clienttrnsport = instance.select(RestfulAmClientTransport.class);
```

i have got isUnsatisfied() property true value (empty instance)
but if i change those to

```
Instance<AmClientTransport> amtranses = instance.select(AmClientTransport.class);
```

than all check are false but get() method leads to recursion creation of whole producer class
i know that i missing something about inheritance but what?

i would appreciate any advice you can provide me.

code part

restfullclient bean

```
public class  RESTfulAmClientBean 
extends BaseAmClient<RESTfulAmClientBean> 
implements RESTfulAmClient , Serializable{
@Inject
private Logger logger;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private AmClientTransport trns;
//private AmClientRequestBuilder rb;
//private AmClientSerializer serializer;
private AmObjectApiSettingsManager amCliSettMgr;


@Inject
@AmClientTransportProducer
private AmClientTransport restfulAmClientTransport;
```

producer bean

```
@Local
public class AmClientTransportProducerImpl {
@Inject
private Logger logger;
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<AmClientTransport> trnsInst;
public AmClientTransportProducerImpl() {
}

@PostConstruct
private void initAmClientTransportProducerImpl(){
    logger.debug("создание экземпляря класса AmClientTransportProducerImpl");

}
@AmClientTransportProducer
@Produces
public AmClientTransport getAmClientTransport(@Any Instance<AmClientTransport> instance , InjectionPoint ip){
    logger.debug("запуск метода getAmClientTransport");
    logger.debug("isAmbig:" + instance.isAmbiguous() + " isUnSatt" + instance.isUnsatisfied());
    Instance<HttpAmClientTransport> clienttrnsport = instance.select(HttpAmClientTransport.class);
    boolean isAmbig = clienttrnsport.isAmbiguous();
    boolean isUnsat = clienttrnsport.isUnsatisfied();
    //Iterator<AmClientTransport> aaa = instance.iterator();
    // Here i have got recursion
    //AmClientTransport trns2 = aaa.next();
    HttpAmClientTransport trns = clienttrnsport.get();
    Instance<AmClientTransport> restfultranses = instance.select(AmClientTransport.class);
    isAmbig = restfultranses.isAmbiguous();
    isUnsat = restfultranses.isUnsatisfied();
    Iterator<AmClientTransport> it = restfultranses.iterator();
    // Here i have got recursion too
    if (
            (!restfultranses.isUnsatisfied())
            ){

    }
    return null;
}
```

AmClientTransport interface just interface

```
public interface AmClientTransport {}
```

client-specific transport interface that extends AmClientTransport

```
public interface RestfulAmClientTransport extends AmClientTransport {
public void execute();
```

}

Local particular transport Bean interface

```
@Local
public interface HttpAmClientTransport extends RestfulAmClientTransport{}
```

particular transport Bean implementation

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "HttpAmClientTransport")
@Local(HttpAmClientTransport.class)
@Default
public class HttpAmClientTransportImpl implements HttpAmClientTransport {

public HttpAmClientTransportImpl() {}

@Override
public void execute() {}
}
```

Comment: I'll be honest, your question is hard to read.  I suspect there's multiple questions in play here.  RE the creation, its not specified that you will only get the instance created when calling `.next()` - that just happens to be how weld does it, OWB does it differently as you're seeing.

Comment: @Ament so can you tell me how to (if it possible) to iterate through beans in instance variable in producer method  , may be some OWB examples for produces factories or some documentation for OWB? in any case fist question is why calling the Itarator<T> cause to create new fabric instance, and how to avoid it?